# Packaging local module with pex

Tags: python, build, setuptools, distutils, python-pex

I'm trying to package my local module with pex and I can't seem to manage to.

I've created a simple project:

```
→ python --version
Python 2.7.10
→ pex --version
pex 1.1.15
→ tree .
.
├── bla
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
└── setup.py
```

`bla/__init__.py`

```
import main
```

`bla/main.py`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   print 'yo'
```

Which to me seems like the simplest project possible.

```
→ pex -v . -o v.pex --disable-cache
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Charly/repos/load_tester/venv/bin/pex", line 11, in <module>
   sys.exit(main())
 File "/Users/Charly/repos/load_tester/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pex/bin/pex.py", line 540, in main
    pex_builder = build_pex(reqs, options, resolver_options_builder)
 File "/Users/Charly/repos/load_tester/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pex/bin/pex.py", line 475, in build_pex
    resolvables = [Resolvable.get(arg, resolver_option_builder) for arg in args]
  File "/Users/Charly/repos/load_tester/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pex/resolvable.py", line 61, in get
    raise cls.InvalidRequirement('Unknown requirement type: %s' % resolvable_string)
 pex.resolvable.InvalidRequirement: Unknown requirement type: .
```

Also tried to do `python setup.py bdist_pex` but this failed as well as it can't find the command.

It really seems like I'm misunderstanding something fundamental but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recently had a bit of a fight with `pex` trying to make it include local modules. What I learned is:

1. You *must* provide a valid `setup.py` file for your module(s) in order for this to work, and:
2. You *must* specify the application's entry point

This was tricky to figure out for several reasons. From reading the documentation, I was able to infer that the correct command in my case should be something like this:

```
$ pex . -v -e usersnotifier:main -o usersnotifier.pex
```

However, when I tried this, I kept getting an error saying:

```
pex.resolvable.InvalidRequirement: Unknown requirement type: .
```

A web search for this error turns up—as its *first* hit—[this Github issue](https://github.com/pantsbuild/pex/issues/360)<s>, which is still open as I type this</s>. (**UPDATE**: This bug has been fixed as of September 2019.) A spent a long while thinking that the above command wasn't working because of this bug. I attempted to downgrade setuptools and made a half-dozen other fruitless attempts to 'fix' the problem before [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47491776/99127) hinted at the necessity of supplying a `setup.py` file. (That Github issue turned out to be a red herring. The `setuptools` bug it mentions has since been fixed, from what I can tell.)

So... I wrote a `setup.py` file. At first, I kept getting that error saying `Unknown requirement type: .` But then I realized that my `setup.py` simply contained a dead-obvious typographical error. The error message emitted by pex in this case was actually quite clear, but it was followed by a large-ish stack trace and the `Unknown requirement type: .` message. I just wasn't paying close attention and missed it for longer than I care to admit.

I finally noticed my typo and fixed it, but *another* flaw in my `setup.py` was failing to include my local modules. `pex` worked in this case, but the generated file didn't:

```
$ pex . -v -e usersnotifier:main -o usersnotifier.pex --disable-cache                                                                                                                     
  usersnotifier 0.1: Resolving distributions :: Packaging paho-mqtt    
  pyinotify 0.9.6
  paho-mqtt 1.3.1
pex: Building pex: 2704.3ms                                        
pex:   Resolving distributions: 2393.2ms
pex:       Packaging usersnotifier: 319.3ms
pex:       Packaging pyinotify: 347.4ms
pex:       Packaging paho-mqtt: 361.1ms
Saving PEX file to usersnotifier.pex

$ ./usersnotifier.pex 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".bootstrap/_pex/pex.py", line 367, in execute
  File ".bootstrap/_pex/pex.py", line 293, in _wrap_coverage
  File ".bootstrap/_pex/pex.py", line 325, in _wrap_profiling
  File ".bootstrap/_pex/pex.py", line 410, in _execute
  File ".bootstrap/_pex/pex.py", line 468, in execute_entry
  File ".bootstrap/_pex/pex.py", line 482, in execute_pkg_resources
  File ".bootstrap/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2297, in resolve
ImportError: No module named 'usersnotifier'
```

Here's the bare-bones `setup.py` that finally worked for me:

```
from setuptools import setup                                                                                                                                                              

setup(
    name='usersnotifier',
    version='0.1',
    py_modules=['usersnotifier', 'userswatcher'],
    install_requires=[
        'paho-mqtt>=1.3.1',
        'pyinotify>=0.9.6',
    ],
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False
)
```

The reason it hadn't worked before was that I was accidentally passing the parameter `py_module` to `setup()` rather than `py_modules` (plural).  ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

The final hurdle I encountered was mentioned in @cmcginty's answer to this question, namely: unless your module version number changes, `pex` will cache/reuse artifacts from the last time you ran it. So, if you fix a problem in your `setup.py` and re-run `pex`, it won't actually incorporate your changes unless you: a) bump the version number, or b) pass `--disable-cache` when invoking `pex`.

At the end of the day, the whole thing turned into an exercise in writing a proper `setup.py`, and running:

```
$ pex . -v -e mymodule:main -o mymodule.pex --disable-cache
```

Here are a few tips I can offer (possibly to a future version of my self):

#### TIP 1

Use `python setup.py sdist` to test your `setup.py` file. It's *surprisingly* easy to screw this up, and there's no point involving `pex` until you're sure your package has the right contents. After running `python setup.py sdist`, try installing the source package it generates (located in the `dist` folder) into a fresh venv and see whether it contains all the files you expect. Only move on to invoking `pex` *after* this is working.

#### TIP 2

*Always* pass `--disable-cache` to `pex` unless you have a good reason not to.

#### TIP 3

While troubleshooting all of these issues, I discovered that I could run:

```
$ unzip mymodule.pex
```

to extract the contents of the PEX file. This can be helpful in resolving any discrepancies that remain between your sdist package contents and your pex-ified application.

Comment: `unzip -l mymodule.pex | less` is sometimes enough to look around, I hate decompressing into folders and have to clean it all up later :)

Answer (score 3):

one way to do is:

1. create create a source distribution (tarball, zip file, etc.) using `python setup.py sdist`
2. then run `pex` command with `-f DIST_DIR` switch

   eg. `pex $(pip freeze) -o aflaskapp.pex -e 'aflaskapp.app' -f dist -v`

Answer (score 0):

Some additional details I discovered. If you run:

```
pex .
```

It will attempt to use the `setup.py` build in the directory. If you do not have that, then `pex` will fail.

By default, `pex` will cache the local package output, so if you change your `setup.py` then use the command to make sure your the changes are applied on the next `pex` run.

```
pex . --disable-cache
```

Comment: Weird. Running this command opens a python interactive prompt in my case. WTF ?